# Having issue while extracting values enclosed within "( )" with regex

Tags: java, regex

I am having issue with regex while extracting values enclosed within "( )"

below is the java problem i m using for the same.  I dont have clue whats wrong with it.

```
Pattern PARSER = Pattern.compile("\\([^\\(\\)]+?\\)");
Matcher listMatcher = PARSER.matcher("((\"as_station_id\", string), hello World (\"as_parameter\",     string))");
boolean listFind = listMatcher.find();
if (listFind) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= listMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    String listMatch = listMatcher.group(i);
    System.out.println(listMatch);
    }
}
```

Actual Output :

```
("as_station_id", string)
```

Expected Output :

```
("as_station_id", string)
("as_parameter", string)
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: i have tested with http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/. which is working fine with online regex tester , but it not working with my java code.

Comment: You don't need to escape the parens in a character class! `[^()]` is enough

Comment: I have changed it to "\\([^()]+?\\)" , still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.find()` will apply only once; you need to loop over it to find all matches:

```
while (listMatcher.find())
    // operate on listMatcher
```

`.find()` will return `false` when there are no more matches.

Also, `.group(n)` will return the text matched by the `n`th capturing group in your regex (and you have none); the special case `.group(0)` will return all that is matched. It is equivalent to `.group()`.

So, your loop really should be:

```
while (listMatcher.find())
    System.out.println(listMatcher.group());
```